# what is the use of stringbuffer being synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

What is the use of StringBuffer methods being synchronized. While one thread is changing stringbuffer, other threads cannot what are practical applications and uses of it

Comment: Depends on your application need. Sometimes more than one thread may access same string buffer .accessed in more than one

Comment: *"what are practical applications and uses of it"* Practically none, which is why they replaced it with `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You question is very hard to understand.  Can you take some more time and provide examples or edit your question to make it more clear?

Answer (score 2):

I see the thread safety as an optimization for correctness (avoidance of undefined behavior).  In multithreaded environments, use of [`StringBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) will at least by thread safe (correct from the point of view of no race conditions, or unsyncrhonized access)

> String buffers are safe for use by multiple threads.

This comes with a performance cost which may or may not affect you.

If you don't need the threadsafety, ie you're in a single threaded environment, or the string is local to a single function call, it looks like you could use [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) which is not synchronized.

Answer (score 2):

> What are practical applications and uses of [`StringBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html)?

Practically none, which is why it was replaced with [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

It's a leftover class from the old days and it was not deprecated because there's a lot of code using it.

E.g. even though `StringBuilder` was added in Java 1.5, the regex class [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html), which was added in Java 1.4, didn't get `StringBuilder` support until Java 9 (see [`appendReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuilder,java.lang.String))).

As the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) says:

> As of release JDK 5, this class has been supplemented with an equivalent class designed for use by a single thread, `StringBuilder`. The `StringBuilder`class should generally be used in preference to this one, as it supports all of the same operations but it is faster, as it performs no synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

String buffer can be safely used in multithreaded applications, because of it does not create data inconsistencies in case of multithreaded environment.

Examples: when I have a string builder which has initial value of "Java" and if thread1 is trying is to add "is" to String builder, thread2 is trying to add "supported" there is a chance that the string builder can become either "Java is" or "Java supported" or "Java is supported" causing data inconsistencies.

In case of string buffer if thread1 is trying to add "is" thread2 will wait so it can only become "Java is supported"